# Active Directory find users from OU without expiry date

Tags: active-directory

I want to find all of the users from a specific group which don't have an expiry date and export them.

I was able to list users without an expiry date

`Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(|(accountExpires=0)(accountExpires=9223372036854775807))(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=EXT,OU=EXT,DC=domain,DC=com))'`

And users from a specific group:

`Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=EXT,OU=group,OU=Customers Users,DC=domain,DC=domain,DC=com" | export-csv C:\no_expire.csv`

But I don't know how to combine them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to combine both queries using ldifde:

```
ldifde  -f c:\expiry.ldf -d "OU=EXT,OU=group1,OU=group2,DC=domain,DC=domain,DC=com" -r "(&(objectclass=user)(|(accountExpires=0)(accountExpires=9223372036854775807)))" -l does_not_expire
```